# Find a word in the lines in file and split it into two lines

Tags: python, list, file

My inputfile(i.txt) is given below:

```
പ്രധാനമന്ത്രി മന്‍മോഹന്‍സിംഗ്  നാട്ടില്‍ എത്തി  .  
അദ്ദേഹം മലയാളി അല്ല  കാരണം അദ്ദേഹത്തെ പറ്റി പറയാന്‍  വാക്കുകല്ളില്ല .
```

and my connectives  are in the list:

```
connectives=['കാരണം','അതുകൊണ്ട്‌ ','പക്ഷേ','അതിനാല്‍','എങ്കിലും','എന്നാലും','എങ്കില്‍','എങ്കില്‍പോലും',
'എന്നതുകൊണ്ട്‌ ','എന്ന']
```

My desired output is(outputfile.txt):

```
പ്രധാനമന്ത്രി മന്‍മോഹന്‍സിംഗ്  നാട്ടില്‍ എത്തി  .  
അദ്ദേഹം മലയാളി അല്ല . 
അദ്ദേഹത്തെ പറ്റി പറയാന്‍  വാക്കുകല്ളില്ല .
```

If there are 2 connectives split according to that. My code is:

```
fr = codecs.open('i.txt', encoding='utf-8') 
fw = codecs.open('outputfile.txt', 'w')
for line in fr:
    line_data=line.split()
for x, e in list(enumerate(line_data)):
    if e in connectives:
        line_data[x]='.'
```

The code is not completed.

Comment: You probably ought to give an example that uses the English alphabet. I can't really follow what's going on with characters I can't recognize.

Comment: It is our local language  malayalam and its all written in unicode characters.

Comment: I appreciate that, but the problem I'm talking about is cognitive, not technical. But maybe someone more multilingual than me could be more capable at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have some indentation problems. I also added `u''` to the connectives to specify unicode since I am using python 2.7.

You need to maybe add a carriage return with the `.` if you want it to split an existing line into two lines...

Here is a start (but not final):

```
import codecs

connectives=[u'കാരണം',u'അതുകൊണ്ട്‌ ',u'പക്ഷേ',u'അതിനാല്‍',u'എങ്കിലും',u'എന്നാലും',u'എങ്കില്‍',u'എങ്കില്‍പോലും',
u'എന്നതുകൊണ്ട്‌ ',u'എന്ന']  

fr = codecs.open('i.txt', encoding='utf-8') 
# fw = codecs.open('outputfile.txt', 'w')
for line in fr:
    line_data=line.split()
    for x, e in list(enumerate(line_data)):
        if e in connectives:
            line_data[x]='.\n'

    print " ".join(line_data).lstrip()
```

Generates this output (extra space because the split comes in the middle of a line).

```
പ്രധാനമന്ത്രി മന്‍മോഹന്‍സിംഗ് നാട്ടില്‍ എത്തി .
അദ്ദേഹം മലയാളി അല്ല .
 അദ്ദേഹത്തെ പറ്റി പറയാന്‍ വാക്കുകല്ളില്ല .
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it, building up a string word by word and adding `.\n` where appropriate:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

connectives=set(['കാരണം','അതുകൊണ്ട്‌ ','പക്ഷേ','അതിനാല്‍','എങ്കിലും','എന്നാലും',
                 'എങ്കില്‍','എങ്കില്‍പോലും','എന്നതുകൊണ്ട്‌ ','എന്ന', '.'])

s=""

with open('i.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in connectives:                
                s += '.\n'
            else:
                s += '{} '.format(word)

print s
```

Note that I added the `'.'` to the end of the `connectives` list and made it into a  [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Sets are a type of collection that are useful for fast membership testing, such as `if word in connectives:` in the code. I also decided to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to put the `word` into the string. This could be changed for `word + ' '` if preferred.

Output:

```
പ്രധാനമന്ത്രി മന്‍മോഹന്‍സിംഗ് നാട്ടില്‍ എത്തി .
അദ്ദേഹം മലയാളി അല്ല .
അദ്ദേഹത്തെ പറ്റി പറയാന്‍ വാക്കുകല്ളില്ല .
```

Unlike the other answer, there's no problem with the leading whitespace at the start of each line after the first one.

By the way, if you are comfortable using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you could condense the code down to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

connectives=set(['കാരണം','അതുകൊണ്ട്‌ ','പക്ഷേ','അതിനാല്‍','എങ്കിലും','എന്നാലും',
                 'എങ്കില്‍','എങ്കില്‍പോലും','എന്നതുകൊണ്ട്‌ ','എന്ന', '.'])

with open('i.txt') as file:
    s = ''.join(['.\n' if word in connectives else '{} '.format(word) 
                 for line in file 
                 for word in line.split()])

print s
```

Comment: It works, but the desired output does not want connectives in it. Otherwise it works.

Comment: @user3251664 sorry, I didn't spot that. I'm not a malayalam speaker myself! It was an easy fix so I've edited the answer. I also added another version which I think is a bit nicer too.